# Is is possible to use WSUS to update sufrace pro devices from sbs2011

Tags: active-directory, wsus, windows-sbs-2011, mobile-devices

We have surface pros in SBS2011 environment is it possible to use wsus in sbs2011 to manage update for surface pro devices? additional notes: so far surface pro devices shows up in sbs server console, and also in the correct OU in Ad administrative center. Just doesn't show up in the wsus client computer listing.

- I already checked the wsus is updated to 3.0 and sp2
- started and stoped wsus service
- restarted server
- restarted surface pros

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/17c66847-c2a9-4418-8a21-3d5270b99a3f/surface-pro-firmware-update?forum=winserverwsus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Surface Pro isn't any different than a Windows laptop in this example. You probably don't have Windows 8 or 8.1 patches synchronized to WSUS, so there are no updates for them on your server.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I completely agree about the os of surface pro and laptop. I joined the surface pro to the domain as far as basic communication with wsus server everything looks fine and under Options> Products and classifications I have win 8 checked. main issue at this point is that the surface pro doesn't show up in the "update services client computers"

Comment: Has the Surface pro checked for updates since then? The check-in is entirely client driven

Comment: During the domain join surface pro joined the domin correctly and in the right OU as well

Comment: checked in for updates = manually check for updates form surface pro? yes that works

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/17c66847-c2a9-4418-8a21-3d5270b99a3f/surface-pro-firmware-update?forum=winserverwsus

Comment: That is specific to firmware, it seems.

Comment: This technet article explains that not only is WSUS supported for Surface, *it's recommended* http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692078(v=surface.10).aspx

Comment: Within next day or two I will install win 8 pro on a vm and see If i face the similar Issue. Can't think of anything else to check

Comment: Thanks Finally worked needed WSUS-KB2734608-x64                                         http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734608